Why some executable stop loops over text file?
I recently came across a problem that I solved by I fail to understand the underlying mechanism. As such, the question's title may be unclear. The situation is the following :

Given the following script :


while read l; do
    echo "$l"
end < file.csv

This will correctly echo all the lines in my file.

However, this :


while read l; do
    echo "$l"
    executable --input $l
end < file.csv

will correctly echo the first line of my file but it will stop reading the file as read will return 0 (or whatever values makes the loop stop itself). The executable I'm using is las2las64.exe if that helps someone.
The fix I found is using read -u 10 as well as <10 to use the file descriptor numbered 10.
What I don't understand is why this behavior is happening ? My best guess is that the executable "overwrite" or use stdin without giving it back to the caller. Thank you to all who would be kind enough to explain this to me.

your guess is probably correct, ie, the executable is consuming the rest of stdin; when you use read -u 10 / <10 you're forcing the loop to use a different input stream while the executable continues to use stdin; another option may be to force the executable to read from a different input stream, say, /dev/null, eg, executable --input $l </dev/null (this assumes of course the executable really doesn't need anything coming in on its stdin stream)

fwiw, this (</dev/null) is a common solution to the issue of programs/scripts/executables undesired consumption of stdin; a web search should bring up plenty of hits; someone may actually come along and close this question with link(s) to a duplicate Q&A that covers this issue

Also see BashFAQ/089 (I'm reading a file line by line and running ssh or ffmpeg, only the first line gets processed!) and the How to keep other commands from "eating" the input section of BashFAQ/001 (How can I read a file (data stream, variable) line-by-line (and/or field-by-field)?).

Aside: Always quote your variables: executable --input "$l"

Shellcheck identifies several problems with the code in the question.  The report that it produces includes links to more information about the problems and how to fix them.  It's a good idea to run Shellcheck on all new and modified shell code.

Note that echo "$l" doesn't work in general.  See (the last part of) Bash Pitfalls #14 (echo $foo).
